# COM (C++) Is Interlock APIs enough for Thread Saftey in AddRef and Release?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, mapi

I know interlock APIs are used inside to AddRef and Release methods of a COM object to increment/decrement the reference count thread safe. But I am trying to understand here is that is using Interlock APIs enough or we need to some sort of other synchronization objects as well e.g. Mutex. So far all sample code I've seen used only Interlock APIs.

**Scenario**- Suppose I've implemented the AddRef and Release methods of a message object as following. Let’s say thread A accessing a message object so m_lRef count is 1 . Once it is done with the message object usage thread A calls Release method

Inside Release method –
    At line#9  -  m_lRef   = 1
    At line#10 -  m_lRef   = 0,  lRef = 0

Thread A suspends at Line#10 and another Thread B access the same message so it calls AddRef method which will set the value of m_lRef   value to 1 at line#3. Now Thread B is suspended and Thread A resumes at  line#11 – m_lRef   =1, lRef = 0 . Thread A will delete the object. Now if Thread B tries to access the same object; Crash is inevitable.

**My question** - Is my scenario valid? if m_lRef =1 then ideally no other thread should be waiting to access the object. But to prevent crash in such unexpected scenario shouldn't we guard whole release method with mutex or CS ?

```
1. STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) CMapiMsg::AddRef()
2. {
3.   LONG lRef = InterlockedIncrement(&m_lRef);
4.   return lRef;
5. }
6.  
7. STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) CMapiMsg::Release()
8. {
9.    LONG lRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_lRef);
10.   if(0 == lRef)
11.   {
12.    delete this;
13.   }
14.   return lRef;
15. }
```

[Reference Counting Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The smarter way to go about it is to never write this code.  The repetition is tedious and ripe for small mistakes.  Plenty of C++ wrappers to do this for you, ATL is good.  It also helps you to **not** use InterLocked.  It is expensive.

Comment: @Hans -  Can you please point me to relevant example/sample to understand of what are you saying. I am new to COM programming.

Comment: ATL is very well documented, excellent books available about it as well.

Comment: @HansPassant, I thought the Interlocked calls were relatively inexpensive and absolutely necessary to prevent race conditions. Does ATL do it differently?

Comment: Raymond Chen has written extensively on this subject, e.g. ["Avoiding double-destruction when an object is released"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/28/474855.aspx) and ["Trying to avoid double-destruction and inadvertently triggering it"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/11/9920543.aspx)

Comment: @Mark - there is no need for Interlocked if the COM object is apartment-threaded, AddRef/Release will always be called on the same thread.  Which is *very* common.  Not the end of the world but InterlockedIncrement cannot beat ++ by a very long shot.

Comment: @MSalters this makes sense to me. Whatever I was trying to explain is pretty much possible when destructor is called. I like the raymond's solution. Thanks for sharing this.  I accept your comment as answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ATL has actually three options: for STA - `1` no interlocked API is used at all, simple incrementing/decrementing; for MTA - `2` "NoCS" version without outer critical section and with interlocked API, and `3` - with outer critical section for various serialization (goes beyond scope of this Q) and still interlocked API for reference counter.

Comment: @RomanR.  I am interested to know more about point#3. Could you please provide some pointer about it ?

Comment: @Rahul: It's regular ATL object designed for MTA, you can create an ATL DLL project (using standard template), and then add COM class there deeisgned with either `Free` or `Both` threading model. The generated code will use ATL base classes in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic goes wrong here:

> m_lRef = 0
>
> Thread A suspends at Line#10 and **another Thread B access the same message** so it calls AddRef method which will set the value of m_lRef value to 1 at line#3. Now Thread B is suspended and Thread A resumes-

If thread B hold a valid COM reference to this object, then thread A alone cannot legally decrement counter to zero. Thread B still holds something so reference counter should be at the very least one when thread A releases everything it has...

If thread B only does its first increment, it should anyway get the interface pointer from somewhere, which assumes an outstanding reference. If something is passing the pointer without a strong reference then it's a caller problem, not the counting problem.

All in all, Interlocked API is efficient and sufficient for reference counting.

Comment: I see the flaw in my analysis. Thanks for clarification. So if I am not wrong Interlocked APIS are used for simplicity  and efficient reasons. Otherwise we can use other synchronization objects as well.

Comment: I think assumption in your response if that "if thread B hold a valid COM reference" but in my scenario problem might happen at the Thread B is trying to acquire a valid reference first time so it  calls AddRef to increment the ref count.

Comment: If thread B incremented it, and it is still using the pointer, then someone else incorrectly decremented it to zero without prior increment. That is, it is still use/caller problem, not the counter issue.

Comment: The point is that you reasonably imagined a thread race issue. The problem is on caller (client) side, and you are looking at valid object (server) side code and trying to figure out where this valid code is wrong. No, it's not wrong at all, it is correct.

Comment: @Rahul, To try to clarify: thread B cannot call ->AddRef() unless it already has a valid reference-counted pointer to the object. Nobody can. Another way to view it: the only caller who can possibly call ->Release() and result in `m_lRef` set to zero, is the guy that has the last valid pointer to the object. Any thread that reaches line 12 necessarily holds the last reference. (All above barring caller mistakes)

Comment: @Euro - I understood that it is caller's mistake. If m_lRef = 1 in the release method then ideally it should be the last thread to release it. I also know that there is no problem with Interlock APIs. But my point is shouldn't we use  mutex/CS in server side code to prevent unnecessary client's gotcha (leave aside performance issue).

Comment: Mutex cannot fix caller issues. You will face all the same troubles that early/incorrect release on one thread might crash another thread, which is under impression its strong reference guarantees object life time.

Comment: @RomanR, MSalters comment above pretty much explain the problem and remedy. I accept your answer though because as it is also correct.